# Mapping one and two presses of the same key with no delay?

Tags: key-bindings

I'm trying to make a mapping which does one thing on the first press of a key, and also does something else if I press the key again within `timeout`. Specifically:

```
nnoremap <silent> <Esc><Esc> :set hls<CR>:let @/="\\<<C-R>=expand('<cword>')<CR>\\>"<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Esc> :noh<CR>
```

…I want pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> in normal mode to stop highlighting the current search (immediately, without waiting for `timeout`), and pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> again to highlight the word under the cursor.

Things I've tried:

- **These mappings as-is:** success, but there's a distracting delay when I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> once.
- **Adding `<nowait>` to the second mapping:** it consumes the key press so the first mapping never happens.
- **Adding `<nowait>` to the second mapping, and `<Esc>` at the end**: `<Esc>` does not put Vim in "waiting for another key" mode (presumably because its a non-recursive mapping).
- **Adding `<nowait>` and `:call feedkeys("\<lt>esc>")<CR>` (with various options) to the second mapping:** hang.

Solutions that seem plausible:

- Temporarily remove the `<Esc>` mapping, send `<Esc>`, and re-add it.
- Have only one mapping which knows how to wait for a second <kbd>Esc</kbd>.
- Somehow put Vim into a "waiting for more keys" mode with `<Esc>` in the buffer.
- Having a mapping which behaves like `<nowait>` but doesn't "consume" the key press.

Any ideas?

Comment: Some options have toggling feature. Related one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762515/vim-remap-key-to-toggle-line-numbering

Comment: you can get the options set, for example whether highlight is set or not. You can code vimscript, like if else statements and react based on that.

Comment: I'm not sure what's your problem with your solution, because you would have the `timeout` delay anyway... So you can reduce the `timeoutlen` value to reduce the delay.

Comment: @SibiCoder Toggling isn't the right behavior. I want to be able to press Esc at any time to turn off highlighting, without waiting for `timeout`.

Comment: @nobe4 I'm trying to get the first press to clear the highlight immediately, and a second press within `timeout` to highlight the word under the cursor.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way: use `<Plug>`, an un-typeable "key" intended for mappings to call each other, to let the single-<kbd>Esc</kbd> mapping prime the other one:

```
noremap <silent> <Plug><Esc> :set hls<CR>:let @/="\\<<C-R>=expand('<cword>')<CR>\\>"<CR>:call histadd("/", @/)<CR>
nmap <silent> <Esc> :noh<CR><Plug>
```

This could be enhanced by adding a name (`<Plug>` → `<Plug>HLSearch`) and/or `<SID>` to avoid a conflict with another mapping:

```
noremap <script> <silent> <SID><Plug><Esc> :set hls<CR>:let @/="\\<<C-R>=expand('<cword>')<CR>\\>"<CR>:call histadd("/", @/)<CR>
noremap <script> <silent> <Esc> :noh<CR><SID><Plug>
```

Comment: Adding the <SID> is important I think as it could otherwise collide with mapping by some other plugin. The only downside of this solution is that is sounds the bell when you type only one `esc` because it does not recognize that mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can try toggling on/off.
A sample vimscript like

```
func ToggleHLSearch()
  let hlsearch_opt = &hlsearch
  if(hlsearch_opt == 0)
     set hlsearch           "Sets hlsearch on
  else
     set nohlsearch
  endif
endfunc
```

can help.

Nw, map it to a key like <kbd>F9</kbd>

```
:nnoremap <F9> :call ToggleHLSearch()
```

(Haven't tested the code Yet. Just a sample)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the snippet! This isn't exactly what I want, see above.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just toggle whether the `'hlsearch'` highlighting is active instead of whether the option is active?  That can trivially be done with `:let v:hlsearch = !v:hlsearch`.